# Flutter simulator won't run because of root and configuration issues

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, ios-simulator

Working on a flutter project I'm in the very early stages of the project and I am getting this massive error when I try to run the project

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
```

```
main.dart:1
```

```
Xcode build done. 8.2s
```

```
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
```

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
```

```
[VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(436)] Could not create root isolate.
```

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(637)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

```
Exited
```

is what  the debug console and terminal give me whenever I try to run, right before this I had just set up my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
 @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
  


}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
 void addNewExpense() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addNewExpense,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already ran Flutter Doctor and couldn't find a problem, Here's the log:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I also ran `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`  I even closed and reopened VScode.

Any help is appreciated, I'm a complete noob to flutter and programing in geral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected your code & I found that you missed the two most important functions to write. which are main() & runApp().

So, here I wrote the whole thing for you. Just paste this code into your `main.dart` file & you're good to go.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  void addNewExpense() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addNewExpense,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ran perfectly and looks nice, thank you so much bro I appreciate it, I dont have enough rep to cast a vote but if I could upvote this I would

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Now, please consider accepting/approving &
upvoting my answer so this post may appear above other results & we both can have a good impression.